# Call variable for a drop down menu in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way for me to select from a drop down using a variable? E.g.

```
FROM = "Leeds Bradford"

    # fill out the form
    depart_from = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_centralDynamicContent_originatingAirportDropDown"))
    depart_from.select_by_value(FROM)
```

I know the above example doesn't work

Comment: From is a string and it is found in option tag > title='LEEDS BRADFORD'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From is a string and it is found in option tag > title='LEEDS BRADFORD' Posted in question now

From what I understand, you need to select the option by `title` attribute. Here is a sample:

```
FROM = "LEEDS BRADFORD"

depart_from = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_centralDynamicContent_originatingAirportDropDown")
depart_from.click()

option = depart_from.find_element_by_css_selector('option[title="%s"]' % FROM)
option.click()
```

Comment: Sorry missed the from variable in question. From is a string and it is found in option tag > title='LEEDS BRADFORD' Posted in question now

Comment: Cool, only issue is that it highlights the option but doesn't really click it strangely.

Comment: @BruceyBandit what if you click it 2 times in a row? Thanks.

Comment: I will try it when I go back to work. I assume clicking twice would work but was wondering why it wouldn't have clicked first time. It should work though

Comment: @BruceyBandit yeah, just in case, here is a backup option: `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", option)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options to select option using [Select class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select)

```
depart_from.select_by_value(value)
#
depart_from.select_by_visible_text(text)
#
depart_from.select_by_index(index)
```

> Edit

A bit dirty work around but you can try

```
# get all the options in the <select>
options = depart_from.options

# find the correct index
int index
for option in range(0, len(options)):
    if options[option].get_attribute(title) == 'LEEDS BRADFORD':
        index = option
        break

# select the option by index
depart_from.select_by_index(index)
```

Comment: Sorry missed the from variable in question. From is a string and it is found in option tag > title='LEEDS BRADFORD' Posted in question now

Comment: @BruceyBandit I added possible solution. Forgive the crude syntax, I'm not a Python man :)